# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality with products

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Question**
For all $K\ge2$,  $a^1_j$,...,$a^K_j$ $\in\mathbb{R}$, $j\in\mathbb{N}$ then:
$$\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} a^1_j ...a^K_j \leq\prod^K_{i=1}\left(\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|a^i_j|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

---

So I get this question from my homework and I tried to use Induction to prove it; the inequality seems well with $K=2$ (CS-Inequality). However, I cannot go further with $k>2$ and to be honest, I suspect this question is not true... Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with forward-backward induction? If yes, does it work in this case?

Comment: Thank you for your hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try using induction and getting the expression in the intermediate inductive step in the form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

As you have noticed, the inequality for $K=2$ holds using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Suppose that it holds for $K-1$ (and we wish to prove it for $K$). Then,

> $$\begin{align*} \prod_{i=1}^K \left( \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} |a_j^i|^2 \right)^{1/2} &\geq \left( \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} |a_j^1 a_j^2\cdots a_j^{K-1}| \right) \left( \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} |a_j^K|^2 \right)^{1/2} \\ &\geq \left( \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} |a_j^1 a_j^2\cdots a_j^{K-1}|^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} |a_j^K|^2 \right)^{1/2} \\ &\geq \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} |a_j^1a_j^2\cdots a_j^K|, \end{align*}$$ where the last inequality uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the second is easily shown.